# How to deal with the slash and %2F in Python?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

Giving the parameters of `Interface=['1/1/1', '1/2/3'], tag=11`, I need to add the missing interface to `json_data[Interface]` and `json_data[Port]` as below. All places except `name` value used `'%2F'` as `'/'`.

Input json:

```
{
    "Interface": {
        "1%2F1%2F1": {
            "name": "1/1/1",
        }
    },
    "Port": {
        "1%2F1%2F1": {
            "interfaces": [
                "1%2F1%2F1"
            ],
            "name": "1/1/1",
            "tag": "10"
        }
    }
}
```

Output json should be look like this:

```
{
    "Interface": {
        "1%2F1%2F1": {
            "name": "1/1/1",
        },
        "1%2F2%2F3": {
            "name": "1/2/3",
        }
    },
    "Port": {
        "1%2F1%2F1": {
            "interfaces": [
                "1%2F1%2F1"
            ],
            "name": "1/1/1",
            "tag": "10"
        },
        "1%2F2%2F3": {
            "interfaces": [
                "1%2F2%2F3"
            ],
            "name": "1/2/3",
            "tag": "11"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with iterate interface list:

```
        for item in interface:
            if item is not in json_data["Interface"].keys():
                json_data["Interface"][item] = { "name" : item }
```

But returned in wrong format:

```
"Interface": {
        "2": {
            "name": "2"
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "1"
        },
        "'": {
            "name": "'"
        },
        " ": {
            "name": " "
        },
        ",": {
            "name": ","
        },
        "/": {
            "name": "/"
        },
```

Comment: You can not have the same key twice inside a dictionary, your "should look like this" Json hast the key `"1%2F1%2F1": {...}` twice. your json is invalid. <jedi-gesture>this is not the json you want to produce</jedi-gesture>

Comment: I added "               if item is not in json_data["Interface"].keys():"  to check if interface key is exist.

Comment: Why are your dict keys URL-encoded?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please show a [mcve]. Current output suggests `interface` to be a string instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

**How to deal with the slash and %2F**

Here's a simple way to convert from `/` to `%2F`:

```
'1/1/1'.replace('/', '%2F')
# Results: '1%2F1%2F1'
```

I'm not sure why you need it in that format, but if it's related to passing it through a URL and you need to escape other characters, you could use:

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.quote('1/1/1', safe='')
# Results: '1%2F1%2F1'
```

**Your output**

It looks like you're accidentally iterating over a string of letters and not a list of interfaces. How are you assigning the `interface` variable?

**Your check for existing interfaces**

Your condition `if item is not in json_data["Interface"].keys()` will not work if `item` is directly from your input in the format `1/1/1` because all of the keys in `json_data["Interface"]` use the escaped format.